# Excel Find Cell Value containing text as a function result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to be able from the keyboard to find cells in a worksheet containing specific text strings. The difference from the standard use of FIND is that in my case all the cells in the worksheet contain functions which reference text from other worksheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `Look in: Values` instead of `Formulas`.
[image: Find]